# Decipher letters (e.g. AABC) to numbers (e.g. 3328) by formula, with provided key

Tags: excel, text, numbers, excel-formula

I have some price codes, for example `BBAXV` and `GGZTR`, to convert to numbers, respectively `22300` and `44000`, according to these rules:

```
F > 1  
B > 2  
A > 3  
G > 4  
O > 5  
J > 6  
L > 7  
C > 8  
E > 9  
Else > 0
```

I'm currently using VBA:

```vb
Function SubstituteMultiple(text As String, old_text As Range, new_text As Range)
    Dim i As Single
    For i = 1 To old_text.Cells.Count
        Result = Replace(LCase(text), LCase(old_text.Cells(i)), LCase(new_text.Cells(i)))
        text = Result
    Next i
    SubstituteMultiple = Result
    End Function
```

with for example:

```
=SubstituteMultiple(A2,$D$2:$D$3,$E$2:$E$3)
```

Is there instead any simple formula I can use for this?

Comment: Inside Excel, with VBA?

Comment: Maybe you could reverse [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667180/convert-numeric-characters-to-alphabetic-characters/32667494#32667494).

Comment: it's only possible using vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any length (within reason)

```
=SUM(10^(LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(A1)))) *  
  IFERROR(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(A1))),1),"FBAGOJLCE"),0))
```

Ctrl+Shift+Enter since it's an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

If the price code is in cell A2, enter this formula in cell B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2,{1,2,3,4,5},1),"fbagojlce"),0)*{10000,1000,100,10,1})
```

Comment: The code is around 3 - 8 Char. But this is sure usefull for 5 Digit Char, In another word, price is around 100$ to 99,999,999$

Comment: Your question was five digits.

Comment: Isn't the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) case sensitive while the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not?

Comment: Apparently not anymore.

Comment: Nope. Was trying to handle the examples given in the question. I disregarded the title since it was obviously baloney. Now I see I wasted my time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess not simpler, but at least an alternative. Text to Columns Fixed width to separate each character (ColumnsA:E). A formula for the transliteration:

```
=IF(A1="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Table,2,0),"0"))
```

in H1, copied across to L1 and down to suit, a table (named `Table`) for the conversion rules (P1:Q8) and finally some concatenation to reassemble the components:

```
=H1&I1&J1&K1&L1
```

in N1 and copied down to suit:

[image: SO3062243 example]

Answer (score 0):

These two User Defined Function (aka UDF) roughly reverse the function provided by the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667180/convert-numeric-characters-to-alphabetic-characters/32667494#32667494).

```
Function alpha_to_num(str As String)
    Dim c As Long, tmp As String, vRPL As Variant

    vRPL = Array(3, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 4, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 0, 5)
    tmp = UCase(str)

    For c = 1 To Len(tmp)
        Select Case Asc(Mid$(tmp, c, 1))
            Case 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 74, 76, 79
                tmp = Replace(tmp, Mid$(tmp, c, 1), vRPL(Asc(Mid$(tmp, c, 1)) - 65))
            Case Is > 57
                tmp = Replace(tmp, Mid$(tmp, c, 1), 0)
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    Next c

    alpha_to_num = tmp

End Function

Function alpha_to_num_two(str As String)
    Dim c As Long, tmp As String

    tmp = "fbagojlce"

    For c = 1 To Len(str)
        If Asc(Mid$(str, c, 1)) > 57 Then _
            str = Replace$(str, Mid$(str, c, 1), InStr(1, tmp, Mid$(str, c, 1), vbTextCompare))
    Next c

    alpha_to_num_two = str

End Function
```

Both have has the advantage of not overwriting replacements.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer